# Get company name input box contact form

Tags: contact-us, contact-form

I want to display the company name by default inside the contact form.
Just like the customer name and emailaddress.

I tried this, but that does not work.

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getCompany()) ?>
```

What line should I use?

Comment: try this `Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName()`

Answer (score 1):

Pre-filled values for user email and name come from the contacts helper, if you take a look there, you will find those functions. To have user's comapny pre-filled too, you can try with something like this :

```
<?php
    if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        echo '';
    }
    else {
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        echo trim($customer->getCompany());
    }
?>
```

directly inside your phtml file.